# How to convert a array of array to array of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, tuples

I everyone,

I struggle to convert an array of array like this :

```py
[
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"],
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"],
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"],
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"]
]
```

to an array of tuples (`array`, `str`) like this:

```py
[
    (["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"], "type1"), 
    (["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"], "type1"), 
    (["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"], "type1"), 
    (["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"], "type1")
]
```

I did find a way to append the type to the array but it's not exactly what I want:

```py
[
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo", "type1"], 
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo", "type1"], 
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo", "type1"], 
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo", "type1"]
]
```

Do you have something better ?
Thanks :)

Comment: you always need `"type1"` in array ?

Comment: how are the types determined in association with the list of lists?  what determined type1 type2 ect with the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Shortest solution: `list(zip(vals, types))`

```py
vals = [
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"], 
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"], 
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"], 
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"]
]

# If you must specify different types for each element
# uncomment the following line
# types = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4']

# If all of them should have the same type
types = ['type1' for _ in range(len(vals))]

# Finally combine vals and types
list(zip(vals, types))
```

**Output**:

```sh
[(['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo'], 'type1'),
 (['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo'], 'type1'),
 (['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo'], 'type1'),
 (['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo'], 'type1')]
```

Comment: @camile-saury Please try this and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: **1.** You can create list with same elements much simpler: `types = ['type1'] * len(vals)`. **2.** You can use [`cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) or [`repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) which won't create long list in memory and will make your expression even shorter: `list(zip(vals, cycle(('type1',))))` OR `list(zip(vals, repeat('type1', len(vals))))` **3.** Your solution is not shortest **!!!**

Comment: type1 was the only type used.  how did you determine to use type1

Comment: @CamilleSAURY Please also consider **voting-up**, given you found the answer useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just initialize a tuple for every element in the list:

```
l = [
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"],
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"],
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"],
    ["foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"]]

new_l = [(i, "type1") for i in l]
```

```
print(new_l)

> [
    (['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo'], 'type1'),
    (['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo'], 'type1'),
    (['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo'], 'type1'),
    (['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo'], 'type1')
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a list comprehension, and for each build the `tuple`

```
vals = [["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo"], ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo"],
        ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo"], ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo"]]

result = [(i, "type1") for i in vals]
print(result)

# [(["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo"], "type1"), (["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo"], "type1"),
   (["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo"], "type1"), (["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo"], "type1")]
```

---

This is equivalent, with a for-loop, to

```
result = []
for sublist in vals:
    result.append((sublist, "type1"))
```